# How to log truncate table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl, truncate

A few days ago, I realized that truncate operations was not logged to my "ddl_trigger_log" table. Hence I searched and couldn't find a definitive answer. I read the book SQL Internals by Kalen Delaney but couldn't find an answer there so I searched online: Some sources say truncate isn't logged and [some say it's minimally logged](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7677) (instead of putting each deleted row in transaction log, it marks the data pages as unallocated and this is why it's so fast). I also read that truncate [can't activate a trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#restrictions). People often compared truncate to drop but drop operations are logged in my "ddl_trigger_log" table. So, I'm a bit confused. I think the confusion is caused by the SQL Server versions (maybe truncate didn't use to be logged in older versions but it's now minimally logged?). I'm looking for a way to log truncate operations in table. If possible, can someone explain how truncate works in the context of logging (and maybe the differences between SQL Server versions)?

Comment: This link might help you - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/26782.sql-server-an-examination-of-logging-in-truncate-table-statement-and-its-comparison-with-delete-statement.aspx

Comment: `TRUNCATE` does seem a bit left out. It doesn't fire DML triggers but I don't see a corresponding [DDL trigger event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-events?view=sql-server-ver15) either

Comment: You are confusingly mixing different senses of "logging". In terms of the transaction log, `TRUNCATE` uses minimal logging and always has done so. In terms of "logging the operation" (as in, recording independently that it has taken place), there is no DDL event for it. This has absolutely nothing to do with what `TRUNCATE` does or does not do with the transaction log, though (confusingly, "transaction log truncation" is a thing, but has nothing to do with truncating tables).

Comment: To capture `TRUNCATE` statements, it looks like nothing short of an extended event session tracing statements and then filtering by text will do (or else an audit trace). As this is clunky and hard to get reliable, it's a good idea to make it so `TRUNCATE TABLE` either needs no logging, or is done through a stored procedure that does its own logging.

Comment: I'm using a trigger on all server to capture ddl events with the following: DDL_PROCEDURE_EVENTS, DDL_TABLE_VIEW_EVENTS, DDL_TRIGGER_EVENTS, DDL_USER_EVENTS, DDL_FUNCTION_EVENTS, DDL_SERVER_LEVEL_EVENTS. And I hope to capture truncate events as well but I don't know how to. I might have asked the question wrong but what I need is not to truncate the transaction log, to be specific. I want to capture truncate events and write to my table.